# building android stopped in the middle of make

Tags: android, android-source, android-build

target Strip: dex2oat (out/target/product/generic/obj/EXECUTABLES/dex2oat_intermediates/dex2oat)
Install: out/target/product/generic/system/bin/dex2oat

ubuntu 16.04 LTS,
make 3.81,
lunch aosp_arm-user,
java version "1.6.0_45"

**I used make -j4, the process stopped at the line above. No errors occurred,
but had some warnings similar to this one:**

aapt: warning: **** string 'map_unknownName' has no default or required localization for 'nodpi' in packages/apps/Bluetooth/res

Can anyone figure out what is wrong?

Comment: Note that `-j4` means that there are up to 4 jobs running at the same time, so the error might be higher in the output. You can try with `-j1` so that only one job runs at a time such that the failing target is the last one shown and you can see what actually failed; or search for the targets that failed in earlier output.

Comment: Which version of Android are you building, and have you modified the codebase at all?  Generally you should try to do a build of your starting point before you make *any* changes, as this gives you clarity if the issue is with the build setup or with something you changed.  Also java 1.6 is not necessarily going to work unless you are building a rather old android version.